# Session was already closed error when i use try with resources

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

```
@Override
    public HashMap<Integer, String> getTestNameIds(List<String> selectedTestnames) {

        HashMap<Integer, String> testNameIdsMap=new HashMap<Integer, String>();


        StringJoiner selectednames = new StringJoiner("','", "'", "'");
        for (String string : selectedTestnames) {
            selectednames.add(string);
        }
        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                SessionImpl sessionImpl = (SessionImpl) session;
                java.sql.Connection connection = sessionImpl.connection();
                PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("select t.testId,t.testName FROM testsmaster t WHERE testName IN("
                                + selectednames + ") order by testId;");) {

            try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    testNameIdsMap.put(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("testId")), rs.getString("testName"));
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



            return testNameIdsMap;


}
```

getting error where we use try with resource with session object.

Comment: Why even th is contraption? Just inject the default `JdbcTemplate` to execute the query, it will use the existing connection or obtain a fresh one. You are making thins overly complex with this construction not to mention it is potentially dangerous as well using concat to create a query is something that should be avoided!

Comment: proper question name

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this contraption. Use either a `JdbcTemplate` or `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` provided by default when using Spring Boot.

Inject a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` and rewrite your code

```
@Autowired
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbc;
```

Then in your method use this to execute the query.

```
String SQL = "select t.testId,t.testName FROM testsmaster t WHERE testName IN(:names) order by testId"; 

Map<Integer, String> result = new HashMap<Integer, String>()

jdbc.query(SQL, Collections.singletonMap("names", testNames), (rs, num) -> result.put(rs.getInteger("testId), rs.getString("testName"));

return result;
```

This will use the same active `Connection` as Hibernate does (when properly using Hibernate and Spring TX management that is!) and will participate in the same transaction as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
     Session session = getCurrentSession();
     Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
     String hql =""  
     SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(hql);
     query.list();
     tx.commit();
} catch (HibernateException he) {
      System.out.println(he);
   try {
        throw new DAOException(he);
   } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```